# Use parent class constructor for child

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, constructor, polymorphism

So, I want to have class Child that has all constructors from its parent class. Is this possible in C++? I have tried `using` statement, but it wont work. Here's what I've got so far:

```
struct Base{
    Base(int i){
        std::cout << "Construcetd a base with " << i << std::endl;
    }


};


struct Child : public Base{
    using Base::Base;

};




int main(){

    Child c(1);
}
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
error C2664: 'Child::Child(const Child &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Child &'
```

Oh, and I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: You need C++11 support for that. It looks like your compiler doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Inheriting constructors is C++11 language feature,

```
struct A { A(int); };
struct B: A { using A::A; }; // defines B::B(int)
B b(42); // OK
```

however, it is not supported by Visual Studio 2013 as documented in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), inheriting constructors is a C++11 feature not yet supported by Microsoft Visual Studio.

The code you posted is correct and [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b315b00493d17e58) as expected with a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler tries to call default `Child` constructor (with no arguments). So to make your code work you need to provide explicit constructor:

```
struct Child : public Base{
    using Base::Base;
    Child(int i):Base(i) {}

};
```

Comment: You are missing the point. OP expects their perfectly valid C++ code to work, but their compiler isn't modern enough.